# What is an example of a power series $\sum a_n z^n$ with radius of convergence 1, yet the limit as $z$ approaches 1 from inside the disk exists?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

If $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$ is a power series with radius of convergence 1, is it possible that f(1) does not converge, yet the limit as $z$ approaches 1 from inside the disk still exists?

Comment: Maybe try $a_n=1$.

Comment: The limit as $z \to 1$ doesn't exist in @SmileyCraft 's example, but there is another point on its circle of convergence where the limit *does* exist. Use that.

Comment: If $a_n = 1$, then $f(z) = \sum z^n = 1/1-z$. The limit of $f$ as $z$ approaches 1 does not exist.

Comment: $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n z^n$